# Get HTML element using JSP

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I am new to Java EE.  In my application, I have a HTML page containing a text area filled with some information. 
I also have a form for the user. Once he submits the form, I use a servlet to process the information. 
Finally I need to forward the Result from the servlet to the same HTML page and update it in the existing textarea. 
I have done creation of HTML page, submitted the form to servlet. 
I am now stuck on how to access the textarea in the HTML page to update my result.

I googled a lot but everywhere people forward the result of servlet to JSP page and create a fresh HTML page using "out" object.

I need to use the same textarea of my HTML page to update the result.  Please help me on achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this helpful to get started and grasp the basic concepts for whatever you're ultimately trying to achieve? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112686

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

*Server-side rendering*.  You can re-draw the whole page, with a normal form submit.  In this case you would put something in `request` scope in the servlet and then access that in the JSP when you draw the textarea.  Note that you are not accessing the HTML textarea in the JSP - the JSP runs server-side code to generate HTML markup, but you are not accessing the browser DOM directly.

This might look like:

- servlet: `request.setAttribute("textareaContent", varWithTextareaContent)`
- JSP: `<textarea>${textareaContent}</textarea>`

*Client-side rendering* Instead, you could make an AJAX post request with jQuery (there are some plugins to help with this).  In this case, your servlet would not forward to a JSP for HTML rendering - it would directly return a JSON object like `{"textareaContent": ...}`  , and you would handle that client-side in your AJAX callback. In this case you *would* be accessing the textarea in the browser DOM directly, in Javascript (not JSP).

Comment: I prefer going with the first approach. But don't we have something in JSP like, getElelmentById on current page and update the content of it.

Comment: No.  `getElementById` would apply if you were updating the page contents client-side.   When you are rendering server-side in JSP, you are rendering brand new HTML DOM elements (usually the whole page), not updating existing ones.